# How do I add an object to a dyamic array of objects using a getArray();

Tags: c++, object

I use a for loop to assign the proper values to the object so the object is completely ready to be added to the dynamic array (*using a dynamic array of objects is required*)

My brain just cant really figure out how I use the address that is returned from the `getCarArray();` function

I have tried creating pointers to an object, which is assigned to the `tempDealer.getCarArray();`
(*Which I learned through debugging that those terms just aren't assignable in that way*)

How would I add the tempCar object to the dynamic array?

**add Car Function**

```
{
    Dealer tempDealer;
    Car tempCar;
    Car *carArr; //here is the pointer that I attempted to assign to the address from 
                 //tempDealer.getCarArray();
    int newCar;
    std::string newVIN;
    std::string newMake;
    std::string newModel;
    int newYear;
    double newPrice;

    std::cout<<"Which dealer would you like to add the car to? "<<std::endl;
    displayDealers(vec);
    std::cin>>newCar;
    int newCarQuantity;
    std::cout<<"How many cars do you want to add?"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>newCarQuantity;
    for (int i = 0; i < newCarQuantity; ++i)
    {
        std::cout<<"What are the specs of the this car?"<<std::endl;

        std::cin.ignore();

        std::cout<<"Enter new VIN:";
        getline(std::cin, newVIN);

        std::cout<<"Enter new Make:";
        getline(std::cin, newMake);


        std::cout<<"Enter new Model:";
        getline(std::cin, newModel);


        std::cout<<"Enter new Year:";
        std::cin>>newYear;


        std::cout<<"Enter new Price:";
        std::cin>>newPrice;


        tempCar.setVIN(newVIN);
        tempCar.setMake(newMake);
        tempCar.setModel(newModel);
        tempCar.setYear(newYear);
        tempCar.setPrice(newPrice);
        //as of this point, tempCar is fully created
        //now its a matter of storing tempCar in the dynamic array that was created, but getCarArray() 
        //can only return the address,
    }


}
```

**Car and Dealer classes**

```
#define PA3_DEALER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Car {
private:
    std::string VIN;
    std::string MAKE;
    std::string MODEL;
    int YEAR;
    double price;
public:
    Car();
    Car(std::string _VIN, std::string _MAKE, std::string _MODEL, int year, double price);
    std::string getVIN(){return VIN;}
    std::string getMake(){return MAKE;}
    std::string getModel(){return MODEL;}
    int getYear() const{return YEAR;}
    double getPrice() const{return price;}
    void setVIN(std::string _VIN);
    void setMake(std::string _MAKE);
    void setModel(std::string _MODEL);
    void setYear(int _year);
    void setPrice(double _price);
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream & out, Car _car);


};

class Dealer {

private:
    std::string dealerName;
    int dealerNumber;
    int numberOfCars;
    Car *carArrayPtr;

public:

    Dealer();
    Dealer( std::string _dealerName, int _dealerNumber,int _numberOfCars);
    Car* getCarArray(){return carArrayPtr;}
    void setDealerName (std::string _dealerName);
    void setDealerNumber (int _dealerNumber);
    void setNumberOfCars ( int _numberOfCars);
    void setCarArray(Car *_carArrayPtr);
    std::string getDealerName(){return dealerName;}
    int getDealerNumber() const{return dealerNumber;}
    int getNumberOfCars() const{return numberOfCars;}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Dealer& _dealer);


};



#endif //PA3_DEALER_H
```

Comment: You must keep track of: 1) What is the number of values in the array, and the maximum number of values that the array can hold 2) Each time a new value gets added to the array, add it to the end according to the "current number of values in the array", and increment it. 3) If "number of values in the array" and the "maximum number of values" is the same you must, beforehand, create a larger array, copy all existing values from the current, full array, to the new one, delete the old array, and update all housekeeping info. The purpose of this homework is to teach you how to do all of this.

Comment: so my solution lies in my updating the size of the array based on how many objects I need to hold?
meaning after I set all the values in tempCar, I need to increment the carArrayPtr by the  newCarQuantity?

Comment: Yes, and keeping track of all the bookkeeping. This is a typical excersize whose explicit and specific intentions are to learn the techniques for doing so. But you don't increment the pointer. The pointer to all the values to the array is still the same. The only thing that's different is the number of values in the array.

Comment: @nixUe -- In short:  `template <typename T> class MyVector { ... you fill this in... };` -- Then `MyVector<Car> CarArray;` will work.  Of course the first part is what you need to implement correctly.  Good luck.

Comment: So I was right in making a statement like this 
Car* cars = tempDealer.getCarArray();
so would that increment statement look like this?
cars += newCarQuantity; 
that looks a little funky, what would the logic of that statement entail?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I haven't used the template form yet, although it seems to be very beneficial in lots of situations so I will definitely research it after this project.

Comment: @nixUe -- By using the template, not only will it work for this assignment, but it will for any assignment requiring a dynamic array.  Of course, you could simply use `std::vector`, since that *is* the dynamic array for C++, and thus make this assignment trivial.

Comment: No, you weren't on the right track. Was what I wrote: "you don't increment the pointer" unclear to you? The pointer, and the "size of the array" is not the same thing.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I apologize, I started the comment before you made the edit about not incrementing the pointer. The thing that needs to get incremented is the  amount of cars that particular array can hold. 
Would that statement look like this?
tempDealer.setNumberOfCars(tempDealer.getNumberOfCars() + newCarQuantity);
my main question is about using the cars pointer to add the tempCar to the array. Im not sure the syntax on that.

Comment: You're confusing the notions of resizing a dynamically allocated array and incrementing a pointer. They are completely different things.   If you don't understand that distinction, then you need to work on that - because, if you don't understand it, you have no hope of getting your code working to resize arrays,

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've now fixed the logic that was preventing me from adding it. My issue now is with a loop that allows you to add multiple cars. It seems like it is overwriting whatever cars that were in there before instead of adding to it. This is because I dont use the vec.push_back(); right? That part is a little confusing because im not adding a new dealer, simply more cars to the dynamic array. Would/How Would I still use the vec.push_back() even if the only arguements that it accepts are Dealers and not new cars.